# Stop UpdatePanel when Inactive

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, updatepanel

Hi I would like to do the following:

Use JavaScript to stop the update panel from "updating" when the browser is inactive, and restart once it’s active again.  I was looking at: [Inacivity with JavaScript](http://www.beyondfusion.com/html/tutorial-autoclose.php).  I was hoping that I could use this to accomplish what I want; can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you very much!

[EDIT]
I am using a Timer for the updates so if I can somehow disable the Timer from JavaScript I think I can do this.

Comment: Can I ask why you might want to do this?

Comment: I am pulling data from Yahoo Finance and I don't want to be pulling data when no one is viewing the page.

Comment: Does the end user have control over when data is pulled, or is the data updated on an interval basis?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527471/. It tells you everything you need to know about the ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Control. For API documentation please visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/bb311028(en-us).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

What's about taking advantage of current window object's 'mousemove' event?
If mouse has been moved, set the timer for 1 min or so, and deactivate event.
Repeat this cycle using setInterval().

It would also help, if the user had snoozed for a while.

Answer (score 0):

add this script inside the head event,

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    var timerEnabled = true;

    function ToggleTimer(btn, timerID)
    {
        // Toggle the timer enabled state
        timerEnabled = !timerEnabled;

        // Get a reference to the Timer
        var timer = $find(timerID);
        if (timerEnabled)
        { 
            btn.value = 'Pause';
            // Start timer
            timer._startTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            btn.value = 'Resume'; 
            // Stop timer
            timer._stopTimer();
        }            
    }
</script>
```

add an asp.net label control inside the update panel for testing

```
<asp:Label Id="Label1" Text="" runat="server" />
```

add an html button outside the update pannel

```
<input type="button" id="btntimercontroller" value="Pause" onclick="return ToggleTimer(btntimercontroller, '<%= ajaxtimer.ClientID%>');" />
```

to check if the timer stops add this code in aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();    
}
```

Just omit the (") mark in the Script because it will cause an error...

Answer (score 0):

```
window.blur = function() { stopTimer() }
window.focus = function() { startTimer() }
```

browser compatibility may apply. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution here: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

i only have IE8 to test with right now, which has a couple issues. first, clicking around the various elements on a page will fire the `focusin` event, so you need a way to check if the timer is already running. that's not too hard. ie8 also fires the `focusout` event while you're clicking around, so we have to delay the actual timer stoppage to make sure the window doesn't actually have focus. fortunately ie8 appears to always fire `focusin` right after `focusout` while you're clicking on the page, so we can cancel a pending timer shutdown on the `focusin` handler.

i think this should be pretty close to a working solution. (adapted from the link)

```
// indicates if your refresh timer is running
var updatePanelTimerRunning = true;

// timer id for shutdown procedure
var killTimerID = -1;

function stopTimer(e) {
    // prepare to shutdown
    if (updatePanelTimerRunning && killTimerID == -1) {
        killTimerID = setTimeout(timerShutdown, 1000);
    }
}

function startTimer(e) {

    // cancel pending timer shutdown
    clearTimeout(killTimerID);
    killTimerID = -1;

    if (!updatePanelTimerRunning) {
        // TODO start the update panel refresh timer here
        updatePanelTimerRunning = true;
    }
}

function timerShutdown() {
    // TODO do actual update panel timer stopping here.
    updatePanelTimerRunning = false;
}


if (/*@cc_on ! @*/ false) { // check for Internet Explorer

    document.attachEvent('onfocusin', startTimer);
    document.attachEvent('onfocusout', stopTimer);
}
else {
    // window.onfocus = stopTimer;
    // window.onblur = startTimer;

    window.addEventListener('focus', startTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener('blur', stopTimer, false);
}
```